# rsync: getcwd(): No such file or directory (2)

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, shell

I want to sync `Server1` and `Server2`'s logs to `LogServer`.

For `Server1`:

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh -p 2188' user@server1:/usr/local/servers/logs/* /usr/local/logs/
```

This one works, but for `Server2`:

```
rsync -avz -e 'ssh -p 2188' user@server2:/usr/local/servers/logs/* /usr/local/logs/
```

It fails:

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: no such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: no such file or directory
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: no such file or directory
rsync: getcwd(): No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: errors selecting input/output files, dirs (code 3) at util.c(992) [sender=3.0.6]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [receiver=3.0.6]
```

Both `Server1` and `Server2` is hosted on Amazon with the same version of `rsync`.

#### I am quite sure that every directory in the command is exists. How can I solve this problem?

**UPDATE:** I have tried `ssh -p 2188 user@server2 pwd`, and it doesn't work:

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: no such file or directory

job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: no such file or directory
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: What user are you using for rsync? I've seen that error when the current user doesn't have permissions to access the directory structure.

Comment: Or when the user's home directory doesn't exist on the server.

Comment: Current user have read permission to those logs and home directory is exist.

Comment: Manually SSH into server2 as *user*. Does that work without any errors? If so, does `ls -R /usr/local/servers` work without any errors?

Comment: Yes, it works without any errors !

Comment: does 'ssh user@server2 pwd' work too?

Comment: @sendmoreinfo, this is wired, `ssh -p 2188 user@server2 pwd` doesn't work! But I can actually login server2 with ssh

Comment: MrROY, could we see some evidence of that?  Perhaps you can cut-and-paste in a session where you ssh to server2, then do e.g. a `pwd`, and maybe a `df -k .`?

Comment: @MadHatter, I have upload the screenshot, thanks !

Comment: The difference between launching a command with ssh and opening a shell is the init part of the shell. Have you done modifications to .bash_rc or .bash_profile ? Can you compare them between server1 and server2 ?

Comment: This happened to me when I wasn't doing anything remote or over SSH.  I changed my source and destination paths to be full paths, not relative to where I was when I issued the command. That fixed ti.

Comment: Use `scp` command instead of `rsync` may be helpful for you!

Answer (score 51):

#### tldr

My currently logged in UNIX user was in a non-existent folder.

#### detail

I had the exact same issue, and my solution was something I had never thought of. In my case `rsync` worked fine for all the time until it stopped during some tests after changes to one of my scripts. The culprit was that my currently logged in UNIX user was in a non-existent folder that was already deleted by a script.

The `getcwd(): No such file or directory (2)` error message was related to `$PWD`, **not** the source, **and not** the destination.

Just change the folder to an existing one (e. g. `cd ~`) and re-run the script. Don’t forget to alter `rsync` paths if they aren’t already absolute.

Comment: I had a very similar issue today when setting up syncing between two folders and getting this message. The source and destination folders clearly existed. I checked if I might have been in a deleted folder but that wasn't the issue. But I was in the destination folder (which was a rclone mounted Google Drive). I changed my working directory to something else and the sync worked perfectly without giving an error.

Comment: I had the same issue and this solved it, much gratitude.

Comment: Likewise; This error is entirely unhelpful without this accompanying answer. This fact that this error doesn't more clearly point the user toward resolving the issue is... probably a bug in rsync.

Comment: Wow, it does make some sense of course, but it also didn't occur to my my rsync from and to two locations I know to exist would fail because I happened to be in a nonexistent working directory. Thanks!

Comment: Wow your answer save me! Same issue when running rsync in a nomoreexist folder